# jquery Check if selected text of a given class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check that all the elements of a class inside a div is selected or not. I have spans inside div and have same class for both div and spans, but mutiple blocks of a group. If I selects all the text of div then I need to perform a task.

Example: div has the class name 'sentence' and spans have 'tooltip' class name. Below is the html sample having two clocks of div (maybe more than 2).

```
1. <div class="sentence" sentence="Where are you going?">
    <span class="tooltip" title="Nǐ, you">你</span>
    <span class="tooltip" title="qù, go with">去</span>
    <span class="tooltip" title="nǎr?, where?">哪儿？</span>
<div>

2. <div class="sentence" sentence="Is he coming?">
    <span class="tooltip" title="Tā, he">他</span>
    <span class="tooltip" title="lái, come">来</span>
    <span class="tooltip" title="ma?, you">吗？</span>
<div>
```

If I select all three chinese letters in 1st div [image] then it means I have selected all three and then after checking I have to get/fetch **sentence** attribute value of 1st div (Where are you going?); and then have to display this value.

How I can check using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what do you mean by 'when I select all three chinese characters', but here's proof of concept for other part:

```
$('span.tooltip').on('click', function(){
   alert($(this).parent().attr('sentence')); 
});
```

this code adds 'onclick' callback to every tooltip span element, when you leftclick span, it will display parents 'sentence' attribute

Comment: your code works on click event but I have to check text select inside of the div.

Comment: @AbhiKumar could you please explain what do you want to achieve and how it would work? you mean that thsi event should fire when you select all spans inside of div?